# On button press get photo ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to get the ID of the photo that a button is attached to (underneath) but am having some trouble.

I'm dynamically inserting using JavaScript innerHTML and it all works fine: Here's my code for creating the images as well as buttons and descriptions etc.

```
for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {

        htmlStr += '<div class="images"> <figure> <a href="' + photos[i].largeURL +
            '" data-lightbox="watches" data-title=' + photos[i].description + '><img src=' + photos[i].thumbnail + ' ' +
            'alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150></a><figcaption>' + photos[i].description
            + "<br> total likes " + photos[i].likes + "<div id='btnDelete'><input type='button' onclick ='unlikePhoto(photos.id)'value='Like' id='btnDeleteID'></div>" + ' </figcaption></figure></div>'
        //console.log(htmlStr);


    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="imagesArea" id="imageArea">
<div class="images">

</div>
    <div class="images">

    </div>
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is for each image dynamically inserted, how can I make the button press grab the id that is defined when creating the image dynamically? or even description etc.\

edit: Image: [image]

Comment: Your JavaScript looks like it creates multiple `<div>` elements that share the `'btnDelete'` `id`? Could you show an example of the HTML/DOM that's generated by that script?

Comment: yeah, each image would have a unique ID though. but I can't figure out how to get that unique ID to be passed to the function? Just added an image

Comment: You picture doesn't really help, what DOM does that code produce?

Comment: Show us your generated html containing the button :)

Comment: is your button also created dynamically?

Comment: Yeah, the button is created dynamically also @meer. . I did, its in the second last line of the innerHTML I believe.

Comment: You are not giving an id to the image in your loop :)

Comment: you can use $('#myDynButton_1').on('click',function(){$(this).parents('div').child('img').attr('id')};

Comment: @Meer Where are you seeing an ID for the image :D

Comment: @BojanPetkovski ; so should I be assigning an ID to each generated image, and then how do I get the image from button click? Thanks

Comment: Can we stop the '(check|see) my answer' comments? The OP is notified, via the Global Inbox (or whatever it's called these days), whenever an answer, or a comment is posted. Incidentally, both comments flagged as 'obsolete.'

Comment: @Bojan Petkovski then HE SHOULD because he is asking how to GET THE ID OF IMAGE.

Comment: @DavidThomas He explicitly asked, how can he access the `id` after setting it to the image, I had answered the same hece I told him to refer the answer, that's all.

Comment: @AlexP2014 if you dont assign an id to the image how can you GET IT ?

Comment: @TJ: because you didn't think he'd be notified of your answer appearing? The OP is notified of new answers. The OP is also notified of edits to *existing* answers. So, your comment adds no value or use, and serves only to litter the comment-space with noise.

Comment: @TJ: I've opened a discussion over on Meta, if you feel I was wrong in my actions (or simply want to observe the discussion): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274311/how-to-deal-with-check-my-answer-see-my-answer-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you loop to something like this where you assign an ID to each image

```
for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {

    htmlStr += '<div class="images"> <figure> <a href="' + photos[i].largeURL +
        '" data-lightbox="watches" data-title=' + photos[i].description + '><img src=' + photos[i].thumbnail + ' ' +
        'alt=”Photo” id=' + photos[i].id + ' width=150 height=150></a><figcaption>' + photos[i].description + "<br> total likes " + photos[i].likes + "<div class='btnDelete'><input type='button' value='Like' class='btnDeleteID'></div>" + ' </figcaption></figure></div>';
    //console.log(htmlStr);


}
```

Remove onclick (it is bad practise to use it) and make it like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteID', function() {    
    var photoID = $(this).closest(".images").find("img").attr("id");
    unlikePhoto(photoID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your HTMLString by setting the value as the `id` or a `data-` attribute of the image and pass the reference to clicked button using `this` as follows:

```
htmlStr += "<div class='images'>"
          + "<figure>"
            + "<a href='" + photos[i].largeURL +"' data-lightbox='watches' data-title='"+ photos[i].description + "'>"
              +"<img id='"+photos[i].id+"' src='" + photos[i].thumbnail + "' alt='Photo' width=150 height=150>"
            +"</a>"
            +"<figcaption>"+ photos[i].description + "<br> total likes " + photos[i].likes
              + "<div class='btnDelete'><input type='button' onclick ='unlikePhoto(this)' value='Like' class='btnDeleteID'></div>"
            +"</figcaption>"
         +"</figure>"
       +"</div>"
```

You can then use jquery to access the corresponding images `id` like:

```
function unlikePhoto(elm){
 var photoId  = $(elm).closest(".images").find("img").attr("id");
};
```

*Side note: Having multiple elements with same `id` is invalid so change it to class name*

Comment: He doesn't have an ID attached to the image :)